# Play video in Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip

How to play video in Bootstrap tooltip element. I was going through the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#examples). What I am trying to achieve is playing a youtube video when the mouse is over some particular text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `iframe`

```
$('button').tooltip({
  placement: 'right',
  boundary: 'window',
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
  trigger: 'click',
  title: '<iframe width="170" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-same-origin" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4qB5gRkq4iM?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
})
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/9x7j5sgb/2/)